# Language of OS may cause trouble to Android SDK installation?

Tags: android, android-emulator, operating-system

Previously I asked for the Android SDK Install, which getting me in trouble as i am unable to parse it out. You can check the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319195/android-sdk-failed-to-install), Now new thing that I want to tell is that at the time of installation of OS window 7, I choose the language of the OS as 'HINDI'. Now I am thinking that the problem is due to the same. Is the problem is as I choose the language as Hindi?

You can see the image of the problem below -

[image]

Help me solving the problem of Android SDK installation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it not the major issues but might this be the problem that cuases your SDK installation failed. I suggest your to change your OS.